# How make Square area with 4 Number?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, nodes, node-modules

how make Square area with 4 number ?

i want to make it with function like this:

```
function generateSquare(XYone, XYtwo, XYthree, XYfour) {


};
```

Need Result:

```
x: 1                    x: 10
y: 1                    y: 10
    | 1 2 3 x x x x x x |
    | 2 3 x x x x x x x |
    | 3 x x x x x x x x |
    | x x x x x x x x x |
    | x x x x x x x x x |
    | x x x x x x x x x |
x: 10                   x: 20
y: 10                   y: 20
```

[image]

It's possible ?

Thank you for all solution...

Answer (score 1):

if you know it is a rectangle you only need opposite corners, or length and width. Make a 2D array with a nested for loop.

```js
let x1 = 1

let str = ""
let arr = []
for (var i = x1; i < 12; i++) {
    str+="|"
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       arr.push(i+j)
      str += (i+j+"&nbsp".repeat(3-(i+j+"").length))
    }
    str+="|<br>"
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str
```

```css
<style>
    #test {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
 </style>
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Your second "square" appears to be 10x11.